# Programatically Binding the value of a ComboBox in a Datagrid based on another Combobox

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, xaml, datagrid

I have a DataGrid which is binded to a observable collection. Within this DataGrid, I have two comboboxes (among other columns). One of these columns is task, the second one is progress.
What I'm trying to achive is the item source for the second drop down (progress), to be updated based on the value of the first drop down (Task).
This is what I have done so far:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="EngTaskEnum" 
                        MethodName="GetValues"
                        ObjectType="{x:Type core:Enum}">
        <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
            <x:Type Type="Sources:EngTask"/>
        </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
    </ObjectDataProvider>
</Window.Resources>

        <DataGrid x:Name="DataGrid_tbl"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding}"
                  AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                  AlternatingRowBackground="LightBlue"
                  CanUserAddRows="True" 
                  CanUserResizeColumns="False"
                  CanUserReorderColumns="False"
                  CanUserResizeRows="False"
                  CanUserSortColumns="False"
                  SelectionMode="Single"
                  CellEditEnding="DataGrid_tbl_CellEditEnding"
                  PreparingCellForEdit="DataGrid_tbl_PreparingCellForEdit">
            <DataGrid.Columns>

                <!--Task-->
                <DataGridComboBoxColumn SelectedItemBinding="{Binding EngTask}"
                                        ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource EngTaskEnum}}"
                                        Header="Task"
                                        Width="Auto"
                                        MinWidth="120"/>
```

The displayed above is the (Task) column, the progress column follow the same pattern. and this is what i tried on the code-behind:

```
    private void DataGrid_tbl_PreparingCellForEdit(object sender, DataGridPreparingCellForEditEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.Column.Header.ToString() == "Progress")
        {
            switch (_taskSelected)
            {
                case"Software":
                    e.EditingEventArgs.Source = Enum.GetValues(typeof(SoftProgress));
                    break;

                case "Hardware":
                    e.EditingEventArgs.Source = Enum.GetValues(typeof(HardProgress));
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

I'm almost positive this is most likely not the correct approach but I have been trying to figure out different things just to see what could works. Please if anyone could provide some inputs would be highly appreciate it.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should bind the second `ComboBox` to an `IEnumerable` property of the class where the `EngTask` property is defined.

When `EngTask` is set, which happens when you select a value in the first `ComboBox`, you set the `IEnumerable` property to the items that you want to display in the second `ComboBox`.

Make sure to implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface and raise the `PropertyChanged` event for the `IEnumerable` property in your model class (where `EngTask` is defined).

Comment: Hello @mm8 I tried what you suggested. I haven't really worked with the INotifyPropertyChanged, so I'm not entirely sure if what I'm doing is correct but, it seems to be that the EngTask is not set until i complete the row. From the behavior I'm observing onced you click on the datagrid, it creates a new item, then it goes to the class and get all the properties, once you click out of the row is that the item gets added to the collection and start setting those properties (if that makes sense). Basically at the creating of the row the EngTask is null until the user tries to create another row

Comment: You can set the set the `UpdateSourceTrigger` to set the source property immediately:  `SelectedItemBinding="{Binding EngTask, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"`